# Question about wget -qO-

Tags: wget

In the string

`wget -qO-`

What exactly am I doing? I've never seen a switch that has a dash *after* the expression.

But, to install Docker, I am using `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com | sh`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is nothing wrong or strange about this.

`-qO-` is the same as `-q` (quiet) followed by `-O -` (output to standard output).

See [the `wget` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).

The fact that the options are squished together is common Unix practice, and an option that takes an option-argument doesn't usually need a space in-between.

The fact that you're pulling something from the web and feeding it directly into `sh` should be more of a concern for you.

Answer (score 5):

**The following `wget` and `curl` commands have the same effect**

```
wget -q -O - https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg

curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
```

You can run it in a Linux terminal to see the result. Basically it's output to system standout stream.

One of the practical examples of these commands are followed by `| apt-key add -` to add apt-key.

For example,

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add -
```

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to

```
wget -q -O -
```

From `man wget`, here's what each option means:

```
-q
--quiet
    Turn of Wget's output.

-O file
--output-document=file
    The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.
```

Continuing the description for `-O`, we see that the mysterious `-` is just a special symbol used by the `-O` option to mean standard output:

```
If ‘-’ is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion.
```

Comment: Additional useful explanation about `-O -` from the Wget [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) : Use of `-O` is not intended to mean simply **use the name `file` instead of the one in the URL**, rather, it is analogous to shell redirection. `wget -O file http://foo` is intended to work like `wget -O - http://foo > file`. Now, `file` will be truncated immediately, and all downloaded content will be written there.